# Pandas: Test for key existence in dictionary

Tags: pandas

Assuming the following dataframe:

```
In [26]: x = { 'a': 9 }

In [27]: y = { 'b': 10 }

In [28]: 'a' in x
Out[28]: True

In [29]: 'a' in y
Out[29]: False

In [32]: df = DataFrame('data': Series([x, y]))

In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
        data
0   {'a': 9}
1  {'b': 10}
```

How can I obtain a new dataframe that only contains rows where the dictionary in the `data` column has the key `a`?

`df['a' in df['data']]` results in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple still:

```
 df[df['data'].apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
```